# C#: Get needed nodes using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

I have XmlDocument object with next structure:

```
<ROOT>
<MESSAGE>
 <some_fields />
 <myDate>
 <myParameter>
</MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE>
 ...
</ROOT>
```

I want to get all MESSAGE nodes where myDate>= given date and myParameter=given parameter.
I.e. something like:

```
MyDoc.SelectNodes("/ROOT/MESSAGE..")
```

Is it possible to do it using XPath?

=================

OK. myDate  has already type xs:dateTime. But now I have next exception:

> //MESSAGE[myDate < xs:dateTime(2012-06-22T11:17:44)]' has an invalid
>   qualified name.

Code is:

```
 XmlNodeList nodeList = MyXmlDocument.SelectNodes("//MESSAGE[myDate < xs:dateTime(" + givenDateTime + ")]");
```

And it doesn't work even with

```
"//MESSAGE[xs:dateTime('2012-06-22T11:47:32')=xs:dateTime('2012-06-22T11:47:32')]"
```

Then I have System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done purely in XPATH:

```
MyDoc.SelectNodes("//MESSAGE[xs:date(./myDate@text()) > xs:date('given date') and myParameter[text()='given parameter']]")
```

*[untested]*

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using LINQ.

You could have something like

```
var nodes = from node in XDoc.Root.Elements("MESSAGE")
            where (DateTime)node.Element("myDate") >= DateTime.Now
            select node;
```

This would select the node elements where the myDate time is the current DateTime or in the future. You may want to look further into XML parsing with LINQ. I find it to be the preferred method of XML parsing.

Another example for you:

```
var nodes = from node in XDoc.Root.Elements("MESSAGE")
                where (DateTime)node.Element("myDate") >= DateTime.Now
                && node.Element("myParameter").Value == "whatever"
                select node;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is very much possible. Please go through the following link where you can get all operators u need.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226440(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226440%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

http://www.javabeat.net/2009/03/how-to-query-xml-using-xpath/

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to work with date in this way? Something like "/ROOT/MESSAGE[myDate>=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + "]" ?

Comment: Please look at folloding msdn blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/healthvault/archive/2011/03/15/xpath-query-for-date-ranges.aspx